# Not loading icon css from static ( 404 Error ) Flaticon and Font-mfizz

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, web

I'm creating a website and i needed a icon of python, so i searched that Flaticon had it.

This is my HTML code:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="{% static "css/flaticon.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{% static "css/font-awesome.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{% static "css/font-mfizz.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<i class="icon-python" style="font-family: Flaticon, serif"></i>
<i class="icon-python"></i>
<i class="fa-gamepad"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

I created a different html just to show this icon and make sure it was nothing related to other things in my HTML code.

And this is the console from the element inspection on the html i ran with Django 'python manage.py runserver' in my localhost using Opera :

GET http://xxxxxxxxx:xxxx/static/css/flaticon.css net::ERR_ABORTED

GET http://xxxxxxxxx:xxxx/static/css/font-mfizz.css net::ERR_ABORTED

And of course, the page has only the Font-Awesome icon, this is the same error i was getting from my main page.

I'm using python and this is my Flaticon.css code

```css
 /*
   Flaticon icon font: Flaticon
   Creation date: 17/03/2018 04:22
   */

@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("./Flaticon.eot");
  src: url("./Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("./Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
       url("./Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  }
}

[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
    font-family: Flaticon, serif;
        font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.flaticon-smart-house:before { content: "\f100"; }
.flaticon-air-conditioner:before { content: "\f101"; }
```

And also, pycharm running Django is getting a url error on Flaticon and Font-mfizz that doesn't happen on Font-Awesome:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `static` files like below, `'` should be inside `"` or vice versa to avoid confusion.

```
<link href="{% static 'css/flaticon.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{% static 'css/font-mfizz.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Then css files you have to correctly see the directory structure.

Comment: The error keep appearing even doing it, and when i try to access the other css files trough the same link, there are no problems

Comment: Flaticon.css and font-mfizz gives me 404 Error, but font-awesome don't

Comment: @BrunoCerk, can you post your directory  structure?

Comment: I got it fixed, really don't know how, but sorry for leaving you without response, forgot to update the post